# SwipeRefreshLayout loading circle is not hiding in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an Android app. I am using listview together with SwipefreshLayout. But when I refresh list view using SwipefreshLayout , the loading circle is never hidden back. I am using it in fragment.

This is layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- place your view here -->

            <ListView
                android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_item_divider_height"
                android:padding="@dimen/list_padding"
                android:divider="@color/whitesmoke"
                android:id="@+id/listview_podcast_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/tf_no_records"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I am using it in fragment

```
public class PodcastListFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    // property variables here

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


.
.
.

refresher = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        refresher.setOnRefreshListener(this);

return view;

}

@Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refreshListView();
    }

}
.
.
.
}
```

The loading circle is never get hidden back as in screenshot below

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to `set refreshing` to `false` after refresh

```
refresher.setRefreshing(false);
```

[From doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

**Update:**
Kotlin:

```
refresher.isRefreshing = false
```